# lack of compiler warning with incorrect brace initializer

Tags: c++, gcc

**Update2:**

As suspected, this does not have to do with having an initializer list constructor. With the comment from R. Martinho Fernandes it's clear that it's just trying to construct an object with a copy of itself that is not detected when using brace syntax:

```
struct C{
   C(){}   
};
struct D{
   C c0{c0};  // << -- compiles without warning
   C c1(c1);  // << -- does not compile
};
```

The question remains. Is a diagnostic required by the standard for this case? I do realize diagnostics is not possible or practical for all kinds of errors.

*I ended up reporting this, as bug [57758](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57758).*

**Original question:**

*Someone I know well* managed to write erroneous code (caused by pure mistyping) that eventually generated spurious `bad_alloc` exceptions. I wonder if there is a good reason gcc (4.7.2 and 4.8.1) does not warn about this.

Is a diagnostic required by the standard for this case? I do realize diagnostics is not possible or practical for all kinds of errors.

This is what it boils down to:

```
#include <initializer_list>
struct A{};
struct C{
   C(std::initializer_list<A*> as){}   
};
struct D{
   C c{c}; // <<- well...
};    
int main(){
   D d;
}
```

Edit: The reason I mention `initializer_list` is that if I remove the initializer list constructor I do get an error: `error: too many initializers for ‘C’`

Which I think is caused by the fact that since there is no user defined (user declared?) constructor, I get aggregate-initialization, which does not work since there is no member (of type C) in C.

Comment: What is the relationship with initializer_lists? This is just a copy from an uninitialised variable.

Comment: what would c{c} mean?

Comment: Since c is not an `A*`, it means a copy.

Comment: but c does not exist to copy from? If i remove the initializer list constructor the error is 'too many initializers for C'

Comment: Oh. That's interesting, then.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, correction, nothing to do with initializer list constructor, but with brace initializer *use*.

Answer (score 1):

Clang++ has the same behavior. You are passing the value of `c0` when it is uninitialized into the default copy constructor without receiving an "uninitialized when used here" warning. (Write a private copy constructor to confirm.)

I think what is happening is [`direct-list-initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). I don't know if a diagnostic is required by the standard, but it's worth filing a bug report about.